# How to trap the expand event in jQuery treetable

Tags: jquery, events, treetable

I'm using the treetable plugin in my web app. 
http://plugins.jquery.com/project/treeTable

I want to be able to perform an action when a specific expandable node is expanded.

I can determine which element is responsible for expanding the node. Its a span with class expander. 
As far as I can tell the plugin doesnt have an event that is fired when the node is expanded or toggled.

I think this is more of a jquery question than a treetable question, but how would I go about doing that.

Comment: is there a live demo available?

Comment: The demo and docs for treetable are here http://ludo.cubicphuse.nl/jquery-plugins/treeTable/doc/index.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because there is no event, what you could do is replace `$.fn.expand` with your own function that performs the logic you need it to do, and then executes the original `$.fn.expand` function. E.g.

```
var originalExpand = $.fn.expand;
$.fn.expand = function(){
  // Do something
  originalExpand.apply(this, arguments);
};
```

That is a crude example.

Comment: Thank you, this is what I was thinking. 
followup question is where should I place the above code? 
I would rather not hack the treeTable.js file, and preferably place the code in my own js, but how would I do that. 
Sorry, Im sure these are serious jquery noob questions...

Comment: You'd want to place the code before any invocations of the expand function by your own code in your own js file. Make sure that your JS file loads after the plugin's JS file. That way you're replacing the function without changing the plugin's file.

Comment: Thank you again for your response. 
After examining the problem a little more, I realized I could just specify the onclick event on the tr tag.